# Android Notification: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK required?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

In the document of the `Notification` class I see this:

> **public PendingIntent contentIntent**
>
> The intent to execute when the expanded status entry is clicked. If this is an activity, it must include the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, which requires that you take care of task management as described in the [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) document. In particular, make sure to read the notification section [Handling Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#HandlingNotifications) for the correct ways to launch an application from a notification.

I've read the materials linked from the above, but I still don't get it. Why is the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag required when an activity is to be started from clicking a notification? I tried the following code:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(
    android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync, title,
    System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifiedActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  // IS THIS REALLY REQUIRED??
PendingIntent pt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, pt);
manager.notify(0, notification);
```

I ran the above code, both with and without the `intent.setFlags` line, and there seems to be no difference. In fact, many code samples I found simply don't have that line. So why does the document says that the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag is a must, and exactly what difference does it make in notification handling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically this flag is required. But since it is required, Android is nice and will just set it for you ;-)

The reason it is required is as follows:

The code that processes the `Notification` and calls `startActivity()` to actually launch the `Intent`, isn't running in a "task". It is system code, part of the `Notification` system. Normally, if you call `startActivity()` and the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is **not set**, Android will try to launch that Activity into the current task (ie: the task containing the Activity that is calling `startActivity()`). Since, in this case, there **is no task**, Android **must** launch the Activity into another task. That's why you need to specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

In practice, this won't always create a **new task**, since Android will first try to find an (suitable) existing task to launch the Activity into. If your app is already running, Android will just launch the Activity into that task. (This isn't 100% true, there are other special cases that can change this logic, but I'm not going to address them here).

NOTE: The same situation exists if you call `startActivity()` from a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`. In those cases, the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` **must be set**, because there is no "current task", so Android **must** launch the Activity into another task.

Comment: From Android 12 you can't start activity from Service or BroadcastReceiver that acts as a notification trampoline. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines

Comment: @R00We Why is this comment relevant to this answer?