# android - provide back navigation when app launched from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, parent-child, android-navigation

I have an android app, which has `HomeActivity` as the parent activity of all other activities. meaning - I always have an instance of it, and if you press the **back** button from any activity it will take you to this activity.

Now, there is an option to launch the app from a notification.

When the user clicks the notification, I start `RidesActivity` (one of the other activites), and in this case if I press **back**, it closes the app (no instance of `HomeActivity`).

What can I do in order to start an instance of `HomeActivity` to the background, and make sure that if the user click **back**, it will go to `HomeActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android goes back to the last activity when you press the back button, but at your point there is no last activity, because you directly start the RidesActivity.

To resolve this you can start your MainAcivity via the Intent from the notification instead of your RidesActivity and put some extra information for starting directly the RidesActivity.

Code for your notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //is important to start the activity from a notification
intent.putExtra("startRidesActivity", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code for your MainActivity, onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*
    * Put the following at the end of this method
    */
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey("startRidesActivity")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RidesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

That's it. Now your Notification opens the MainActivity and the MainActivity start directly your RidesActivity. If you click then the back button, you should see your MainActivity and not your homescreen.

Comment: great answer! thanks a lot. just so I know, why is it important to add the NEW_TASK flag when you start activity from notification? in what other cases you need to put this flag?

Comment: It is important, because the notification doesn't run in the context of your app and android need this information to start your app in a "new task". Here it is good explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886618/android-notification-intent-flag-activity-new-task-required

Comment: got it. also, if I get the notification while I am in the app, and I click it - I will have activities in this order: RidesActivity->HomeActivity->any other activities that were running. should I kill all other activities when notification clicked?