# Start new Activity from BroadcastReceiver will resume existed Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I had `Activity` A(`launchMode` is `singleTask`) and B. In `onCreate()` of A, I triggered an alarm, which will activate a `BroadcastReceiver` after some time. Then I pressed home button to hide A.

In that `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()`, following code will be executed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And then I found B was launched normally, but A will also be resumed. I don't know why and don't like that behavior.

Let's imagine: user opened you app's  `Activity` A, pressed home button and opened another app's `Activity` B, then a `BroadcastReceiver` is activated and `Activity` C of your app is opened, user did some stuff there and then he pressed back button. He should see B instead of A, right?

How can I forbid this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found an appropriate solution by myself, again...

**Add `android:taskAffinity="hello.world"`(Any string different from your app's package name and contains at least one point is good) for `Activity` A in `AndroidManifest.xml`.**

**Reason?** When start an `Activity` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, it will check if there was a task existed with same `taskAffinity`. If yes, it won't create new task but will be pushed to that task directly. In our case, since we don't have `android:taskAffinity="..."` written, all Activities have same `taskAffinity`. As a result, when B is launched from `BroadcastReceiver`, it is added to default app task where A is existed in, too. **I think**, then the default app task will be activated and all Activities inside it are going to be pushed into top of back stack. Then we know the result: pressing back button in B will lead us to A.

**Other behavior change?** Yes. If using this method, B cannot have multiple instances unless launch it with **one more** flag: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

**Interesting related discovery?** Yes. I find that if pressing home button in A and launching B in `BroadcastReceiver` soon in 5 seconds, then B will display after a delay. But if B is launched after more seconds, it will display very quickly. This is a protection by Android system, for more details, you can reference [Delay while launching activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927102/delay-while-launching-activity-from-service). Trust me, this is very very inconspicuous but interesting(And no solution:).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to add one more flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

App's current behavior can be explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897207/2930834).
As suggested in linked answer,

> If your app is already running, Android will just launch the Activity into that task.

So extra flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` will help.

---

**Edit**

Based on discussion in comment, 
You can check if Your activity is in background or foreground ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469643/2930834) can help) and depending upon result use Intent flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`.

Comment: It's an interesting flag while makes no difference.

Comment: I guess the problem is Activity is getting started in Already available TASK, what if you explicitly mentioned "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK"replacing "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY".

Comment: Yes, using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` helps. However, if we don't press home button in A and still launch B, then A will be destroyed because of that flag, which isn't perfect for me.

Comment: I thought about that just a few second after I saw `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and realized that it can help. However, I have many Activities and I think it's not elegant to judge if any of them are existed. But still thank you.

Comment: If possible let me know, what solution you implemented.

Comment: please see my answer~

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line of setting in AndroidManifest.xml for B Activity.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Use the simplest way to start the B activity

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,B.class));
```

But this way has a problem,it will influence all places when B activity is started.